# How to refresh a C array after using assembly to sort

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, bubble-sort

I have been working on a program that will do a bubble sort for n integers. I have hit a wall, as I do not know to refresh the array once my assembler operation are done. Any suggestions would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int *input;
int output;
int i;

int main(void)
{
scanf("%d", &n);

input = (int *)malloc(sizeof(n));

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &input[i]);
}

__asm
{
    mov ebx, input
    mov esi, n


outer_loop:
    dec esi
    jz end_outer
    mov edi, n

inner_loop:
    dec edi
    jz outer_loop

compare:
    mov al, [ebx + edi - 1]
    mov dl, [ebx + edi]
    cmp al, dl
    jnl inner_loop

swap:
    mov [ebx + edi], al
    mov [ ebx + edi - 1], dl
    jmp inner_loop

end_outer:



}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", input[i]);
}
scanf("%d", &output);
}
```

Comment: Define "refresh" in this context. What can't you do?

Comment: There's something deeply disturbing about implementing an algorithm as slow as bubble sort in a language as fast as assembly :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it simply reprints the original array. I can't get it to print the resorted one.

Comment: You might have a problem because in the assembly code you assume an int has size 1 byte, whereas an int is probably more than that (probably 32 bits).

Comment: "As fast as assembly" is a weird statement.  This code will be slow.  Bubble sort is slow in any language.  I think Ryan is wasting his time.  Simply using `qsort` from the standard library will beat out this code.

Comment: Careful with the "wasting his time comments". He's wasting his time if the idea is to have a fast sort, but not if the point is to learn how to work the assembly embedding feature of his compiler...

Comment: My x86 assembly is weak, but isn't the inner loop always running over n items when is should get shorter on each pass?

Comment: I also do not think he is wasting his time. There are applications in which being able to optimize code using assembler can be useful or even needed. I could name at least one good example.

Comment: @dmckee: You are right, otherwise the two indices will cross each other.

Comment: dmckee, Griogio - You guys are right, I shouldn't have written with such a discouraging tone.  Ryan, don't feel dissuaded by my hyperbole/cynicism.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing to "refresh".  Your code runs.  `ebx` contains `input` and that's that.  (Hint: Your C code also gets transformed into assembly.  Looking at what your compiler generates through a disassembler might give you some insight.)

That said I see some problems:

```
input = (int *)malloc(sizeof(n));
```

This allocation is not big enough and your program will crash.  You want to allocate `sizeof(int) * n`.  You should also check the allocation for errors.

```
mov al, [ebx + edi - 1]
mov dl, [ebx + edi]
cmp al, dl
```

Kind of verbose.  You should be able to do register-to-memory comparisons.  (eg. `cmp al, byte [ebx + edi]`)

<s>Not to mention it's a complete waste of time to implement bubble sort in assembly.</s> Rephrase: Learning assembly is great, but it would be a bad idea to use this in anything that matters.  One of the most important things about knowing assembly is knowing when you don't need to use it.  You'd probably find very often that what your compiler generates is good enough.  Let's also not forget that a good algorithm in C will beat a bad algorithm in assembly, such as bubble sort.

@Giorgio also raises a good point in the comments.  Your assembly is comparing and sorting bytes.  You want to be doing things like this:

```
mov eax, [ebx + edi - 4]    ; assumes edi is a byte offset, see next comment
mov edx, [ebx + edi]
```

And instead of `dec edi` etc., you want to do:

```
sub edi, 4
```

Your swap would also have to be re-done to use 32-bit quantities.

This is of course assuming `int` is 32 bits, which may not be the case.  If you're using (non-standard) inline assembly it's probably fair that you're doing this - it means you're already targeting a particular compiler.  (Based on the syntax I'd say VC++)  Nitpickers might say you should use `int32_t` instead of `int`.

Note I'm not sure if this is the only problem, I haven't looked at your code too thoroughly.

Comment: Aren't al and dl too small to hold an int? Shouldn't edi and (edi - 1) be multiplied by sizeof(int)?

Comment: I am curious to see the solution. I guess you have to store sizeof(int) in a C variable and then read that from assembly.

Comment: You guys are right to flame me for the "waste of time" comment, so I've rephrased it.

Comment: @Giorgio - I think if he's bothering to use `__asm` he's already making assumptions about the sizes of `int`, etc.  It would be very strange to write runtime code to detect the size of integers, rather than just assuming that these are the size of a general purpose register.  Maybe rather than `int` it should be `int32_t`.

Comment: No flame intended -- sorry if it came across as such. Rephrased version is *much* better.

Comment: @asveikau: You are probably correct, using sizeof is probably too much. It would only make sense if there are two different compilers for the same architecture that assign different sizes to int.

Comment: Regarding the swap: x86 has a special instruction for swapping values: `XCHG <a> <b>`, one of the operands must be a register.

Comment: @datenwolf Doesn't the `xchg` instruction implicitly have a `lock` prefix?  If so that solution might not be best for a multiprocessor machine.

Comment: @asveikau: Yes it does because it is atomic. It strongly depends on the usage scenario. If code size matters and you're on a single core machine, then XCHG is better suited. Think of an embedded/mobile system with Atom CPU. Using XCHG on such one will save code size and CPU cycles to will enhance energy efficiency. On a multicore machine a dual mov may be better. But this depends on the usage scenario: If you expect the program to be single threaded and run when there's little overall system load don't worry about those other cores. If you want best parallelization, don't use it.

Comment: @asveikau: Not to forget that XCHG is prefixed with a LOCK only if one of the operands is a memory location. If the XCHG is between registers, then it is LOCK-free.

Answer (score 2):

I will also give it a try.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;
int *input;
int output;
int i;
int s;

int main(void)
{
    s = sizeof(int);
    scanf("%d", &n);

    input = (int *)malloc(sizeof(n));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &input[i]);
    }

    __asm
    {
        mov ecx, s
        mov ebx, input
        mov esi, n
        mul esi, ecx

    outer_loop:
        sub esi, ecx
        jz end_outer
        mov edi, esi

    inner_loop:
        sub edi, ecx
        jz outer_loop

    compare:
        mov edx, [ebx + edi]
        sub edi, ecx
        mov eax, [ebx + edi]
        add edi, ecx

        cmp eax, edx
    jnl inner_loop

    swap:
        mov [ebx + edi], eax
        sub edi, ecx
        mov [ebx + edi], edx
        add edi, ecx
        jmp inner_loop

    end_outer:
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", input[i]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &output);
}
```

I used variable s to hold the size of an integer. To my knowledge it is not allowed to use an indirection like

```
mov eax, [ebx + edi + ecx]
```

therefore I had to add separate add and sub. It is not very nice, does anyone see a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to intend to allocate and input an array of `n` `int` values. (Although the memory size in your `malloc` is incorrect, as has already been noted).

But then you proceed to sort your array as an array of `n` *bytes*. Why are you sorting bytes instead of sorting `int`s?

Even if your sorting algorithm is implemented correctly (as byte-sorting implementation), the end result will look totally meaningless, since you are printing your array as an array of `int`s in the end.

First make up your mind what is that you are trying to work with: `int`s or bytes (`char`s) and then act accordingly and consistently.